# Why isn't my Block showing up | Minecraft Forge 1.12.1

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've registered the Block (or at least, I think I did) using this code:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onRegistryRegisterBlock(RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
    event.getRegistry().register(MyMainModClass.creepyFace01);
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onRegistryRegisterItem(RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
    event.getRegistry().register(MyMainModClass.itemCreepyFace01);
}
```

The unlocalized name of the Block I'm trying to register is "creepy_face_01". Here's how I created the references in my main mod class:

```
public static Block creepyFace01 = new CreepyFace01();
public static ItemBlock itemCreepyFace01 = new ItemBlock(creepyFace01);
```

And here's the Block class:

```
String unlocalizedName = "creepy_face_01";
float hardness = 60f;
float resistance = 4000f;

public CreepyFace01() {
    super(Material.ROCK);
    this.setUnlocalizedName(unlocalizedName);
    this.setRegistryName(MinecraftStoryMod.modID, this.unlocalizedName);
    this.setHardness(hardness);
    this.setResistance(resistance);
    this.setHarvestLevel("axe", 3);
    this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.DECORATIONS);
}
```

And yes, the class extends Block. I think I registered the event handlers correctly since I included @Mod.EventBusSubscriber in my code. I'm also using proxies. I'm using Minecraft Forge 1.12.1 14.22.0.2469.

Comment: Where are the event listeners located? Have you registered them properly? Edit: also, what do you mean by "not showing up," is it not in the game at all? Is it missing a texture? Can you just not see it in the creative tabs? Edit again: is there somewhere we can see the entire classes, like github or something? Without seeing the whole thing, we're missing a lot of context...

Comment: The event handlers are all registered coz I have @Mod.EventBusSubscriber in my code (mentioned this). It's not in the game at all, and this mod is a private one (temporarily, until I finish) which means that I cannot share the code in GitHub atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `@Mod.EventBusSubscriber` to register your event handler class, the handler methods (`onRegistryRegisterBlock` and `onRegistryRegisterItem` for you) need to be static, otherwise they will not be called.

Comment: ...and if you're not, you need to register a new instance of your event handler class with the event bus.

Comment: Well... that explains why all the command mods I've been working on wouldn't work ._. will try this out